# PHP Making multiple API calls simultaneously without timing out

Tags: php, api, oauth

I have an application that performs a GET request to a REST API endpoint to retrieve a list of posts. The response returns a list of posts, however does not include all the fields necessary. Because of this, I have to do another GET request to a different endpoint to retrieve all fields of a given post, this call is inside a loop.

```
$posts = $client->getPosts(); // Get list of posts

foreach ( (array) $posts as $post ) {
    $post = $client->getPost( $post->postID ); // Get more information for this post

    // Do something
}
```

Obviously the issue with this is if the initial request returns a large list, the application will timeout during the loop. I'm looking for a better way to break this up to prevent timing out and successfully complete all the API requests. The caveat is this script runs on a CRON schedule so I *think* we cannot do this using JS.

Any help is much appreciated in advance

Comment: If this is being done via CLI PHP, it shouldn't have any timeout. Are you running this on your own servers or hosted somewhere? If hosted, they may have set a timeout.

Comment: If you are using Curl, just use the curl_multi_ feature

Comment: It's hosted locally right now, using Guzzle to make the requests

Comment: How many posts do you have in your $posts array? To get the thinks done simultaneously you need some Guzzle-Clients because every client can execute one request. But maybe the Server you are calling is breaking down if you penetrate them with too many connections.

Comment: @ThomasDeutschländer It varies but needs to be able to support well over 100.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not what you want to hear: If you're requesting a bunch of Posts and if you need a sub request for every of the 100 Posts to get detail informations, you got a design issue of your app. For sure it is possible to solve that problem with a generator and the initialisation of more than one guzzle client but that is a very bad solution. If you have the control of the getPosts() method, try to add the detail information directly or add another endpoint which has the informations.

Comment: @ThomasDeutschländer I agree that would be ideal but it's a third party API and unfortunately how it's setup